# How to I dump a lmdb database for backup purposes?

Tags: lmdb

I want to dump a LMDB database. I tried the mdb_dump command, but it's not obvious what combination of options to use:

> ## mdb_dump -s $PWD/foobar-00.lmdb >foobar-00.lmdb.dump
>
> usage: mdb_dump [-V] [-f output] [-l] [-n] [-p] [-a|-s subdb] dbpath

Comment: Does this help you at all http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/man1/mdb_dump_1.html

Comment: Sorry, no. It has no examples, so I cannot figure out the correct sequence of options to get a working dump going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer: Give a LMDB database at /path/to/foobar-00.lmdb, dump it as follows

> ## mdb_dump -n /path/to/foobar-00.lmdb>foobar-00.lmdb.dump

To restore,

> ## cd /path/to; mdb_load -n -f foobar-00.lmdb.dump

These utilities are in package lmdb-utils (for Ubuntu).